# Angular don't detect the correct version of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have created an angular project
Here is my current version of node

```
     nvm ls

->     v18.10.0
        v20.4.0
         system
default -> 18.10 (-> v18.10.0)
```

When trying to create a component

```
sudo ng generate login

Node.js version v12.22.9 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.14 or v18.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

I'm confused, what's wrong ?

Comment: in a command line window run `node -v` what version does it show you have installed?

Comment: It also prints v18.10.0

Comment: Try `sudo nvm ls` and `sudo node -v`. I suspect the elevated privilege might come into play on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using latest version of angular which will not compatible with your installed node version. Update node version in your system.
check version compatablity here : https://angular.io/guide/versions

Comment: I checked the website, everything seems correct : from ng -v I obtain : 
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
    
erwan@erwan-pc:~/Images/eosya_app/frontend/eosya_frontend$ node -v
v18.10.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).